# Version Conflict while using default Google recommendations

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio

I am trying to use several functionalities of Firebase at the same time, which requires several implementations. Namely, cloud storage, database, and authentication. However, when using the Firebase interface in android studio and clicking on "add *** to your app" to add the implementation I'm getting the conflict 
"Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services"

```
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.0.0'


implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.6.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.8.0'
```

Those are the ones im using ( there is a red line under the auth one and when I hover over it, it says all libraries must use the same Version ... 
Any ideas how to solve this ?

Answer (score 1):

change this:

```
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.6.0'
```

into this:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok After some Trial and Errors, I found out that I have to use 11.6.0 on all of them since Auth 11.8.0 Does not exist yet.